# class equation of order $10$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is it a class equation of order $10$

> > $10=1+1+1+2+5$.

As far as I know for being a class equation each member on RHS has to divide $10$ and should have at least one $1$ on RHS, which is the case. So I think it is a valid class equation.Is it correct?

Comment: I guess by your question you mean does (1,1,1,2,5) occur as the (irreducible character) degree sequence of a finite group.  (Equivalently, these numbers are the orders of the conjugacy classes.)  If so, it's well known that such a group must have order the sum of the squares of the degrees, which in this case is 32.  So you can answer this question by checking the character tables of all groups of order 32 (easily done in computer algebra packages like GAP or Magma or Sage).

Comment: This can not be a class equation as 3 does not divide 10.(Think!!!)

Answer (score 4):

This cannot be a class equation of a group of order 10 because the $1's$ in the class equation correspond to all those elements which lie in the center $Z(G)$ of the group. But $Z(G)$ is a subgroup, so by Lagrange it's order (which in this case will be $3$) must divide $|G|=10$. This is a contradiction.